# Firebase push notification error on crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have been using firebase to send push notifications,i have tested on multiple devices at my end and there is no error,but i have been constantly getting the following error on "crashlytics" for many users having the app.

```
> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage$Notification.getBody()' on a null object reference
com.testapp.main.Services.FireBaseMsgService.onMessageReceived
```

I am sure the body parameter is not null and that is why i am not having the error at my end but why is this error coming up.

I am unable to reproduce the crash at my end...Any ideas ?

body parameters :

```
{"registration_id":["eYpuIurd3AA:APA91bFoKMAY1M52L_DQaXXvJO4NeVVDvRLr9l1T-55-2_aSz9CCl2ubeQG1CdXMJbfbWhHkIBOfqYrrTUirZR0Rd3r0ZJqQu6L3d7eSOpnR7erx6aPFQV3jEFNhTLAJEB4S9pVLcpyA","cYVtK9SPvbM:APA91bH3hsTrKJx28nyr6ySeQRRlcxNJQ9B_ze7jc8lUMU2e-p-dBNGUrElIVt1F1SmxZo5vi-J-uFTOzoAVQXjLFjY9R4A_WCfovCijYa57cVLuYEyJeCy90_Sb5zTheer97QvPe2Kj","cV92vqP-uzM:APA91bE8sXvuJGj005t5NC77rZ2mkMjSTiPG_aqqPk4mhuErjR4cAALOf3IomYB7yjQca60IRHv4VFNF0SVawrZN2qhgBpkjEGLasUlXtwlLvyUPkbj9nEl6lXEKhvDOuD4sxmG2r83B"],"priority" : "high",
      "notification" : {
        "body" : "Some text",
        "title" : "some title",
        "click_action":"Activity_Disc"
      }
    }
```

Client End code :

```
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) { 

            String messagetext = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();


        sendNotification(messagetext);

}
```

Comment: Please post your code also

Comment: @VinayakB posted.

Comment: onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)  code also

Comment: Done. @VinayakB 
Its working perfectly fine at my end.

Comment: You are not checking remoteMessage.getNotification()  is null or not. you should check that otherwise it will cause NPE

Comment: check this  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Comment: when the body is not null in any case then why should i  ? and also i am not getting any error expect crashlytics. @VinayakB